# Trying to install packages with pip properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-2.x

This is a very vague question but I am really stuck. I have been working with python for a little bit to try and use some of their functions in opencv (cv2) and other open source libraries. But whenever I try and use pip I will always get an error about improper installation or more commonly when trying to import the installed package idle throws an error that a line of code in the library that is causing an exception. This does not just happen to one library but nearly all of them (I have tried stuff like opencv, tensorflow, urllib). I have tried reinstalling different versions of python (multiple times) and reinstalling it but none of that seems to work. I don't know what to do but really want to be able to use these tools. I use windows 10 and use the default "User" user on admin. 
Any help on possible options would be most appreciated!

Comment: Do you have MS build Tools?

Comment: Please show us the exact errors, not just "an error about improper installation"!

Comment: I understand that you have been so frustrated and tried out every single answer and method possible. But it'd help to see the errors you're getting. Just re-do what you're trying to do and show the output (maybe you might even solve it in that process ;) )

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me as well.

In my case I wanted to work with Anaconda and Spyder. I was following some books and tutorials saying how to install stuff with the pip and so on, but it didn't work. What solved it was to install PyCharm and use those same pip functions directly on the PyCharm console (not the windows cmd). Then everything worked automatically and I have whatever library I installed from PyCharm available at Spyder without doing anything else.

Summary:

1. Get Pycharm -> [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)
2. use the same pip install directly in the PyCharm console
3. A-Hopefully it will work
4. If it doesn't: Can you elaborate on which IDE are you using? Most likely there is someone here who can help you.